# Google Cloud Dataprep - Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

Are there any functions like discretization, normalization and data transformation (categorical to numeric) on Google Cloud Dataprep?

Answer (score 1):

Discretization is available on DataPrep as [Binning](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Prepare-Data-for-Machine-Processing_132067513#binning).
Documentation page does not show version information or page history, so I'm not sure when this feature is added to DataPrep.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a list of [normalization techniques](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Normalize-Numeric-Values_57344585) among which Trim whispace, Standardize units, etc. From the docs:

> **Trim whitespace**
>
> You can trim out whitespace from an individual column via transform.
> The TRIM function applied to string values removes the leading and
> trailing whitespace:
>
> ```
> set col: myCol value: TRIM(myCol)
> ```

Also there is a list of **transform operations** classified by category: Initial parsing, Manage columns, etc. For example, in the [Aggregate Transform](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Aggregate-Transform_57344630) doc:

> ...
>
> **Basic Usage**
>
> ```
> aggregate value:MAX(totalSales) group: Region
> ```
>
> **Output:** Reshapes the dataset to two columns: The new Region column contains the unique values from the source Region column, and the
> max_totalSales column contains the maximum value of the values in the
> original totalSales column for each value in Region.
>
> ......

See the [the complete list of transforms](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Transforms_57344629) for more details.